# I am trying to set a cookie in supertest but it does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

I am trying to set a cookie session to a post request in supertest but I cannot. This is my test code:

```
const app = express();

app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(json());
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    signed: false,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test",
  })
);
   
    
    it("this is a test", async () => {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post("/api/users/current")
        .set("Cookie", [
        'express:sess=eyJqd3QiOiJleUpoYkdjaU9pSklVekkxTmlJc0luUjVjQ0k2SWtwWFZDSjkuZXlKcFpDSTZJakV5TXpRaUxDSmxiV0ZwYkNJNkluUmxjM1JBZEdWemRDNWpiMjBpTENKcFlYUWlPakUyTkRZeE5qazVNREI5LjZybE8zODB2RG1PN0J4cFlhRERZSnBScmhrMEc2X3pvN3BBd2MxYU5rMVEifQ=='
          ])
        .send({});
    
      expect(response.get("Set-Cookie")).toBeDefined();
    });
```

and this test fails because `response.get("Set-Cookie")` is undefined

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just a quick guess. You might not have cookie parser active / added to your test environment.

Answer (score 7):

New versions of `cookie-session` will require the session to start with the keyword `session`:

```js
"session=eyJqd3QiOiJ..."
```

As opposed to `express:sess`:

```js
"express:sess=eyJqd3QiOiJ..."
```

Another thing that helped me was the use of the `agent`. I did that based on the [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) docs.

```
import express from 'express';
import request from 'supertest';

const app = express();
const agent = request.agent(app); // <-- Important

const response = agent // <-- Request through agent
  .post('/api/users/current')
  .set('Cookie', [
    'session=eyJqd3QiOiJ...', // <-- No 'express:sess' (Cropped for demo)
  ])
  .send({});
```

Comment: May we please have the link to the documentation you're referring to?

Comment: Hello @SudharshannD - Yes of course. I added an image and the link to the supertest docs. I hope it helps.

Comment: @SudharshannD I added a comment about the `agent`. That made a difference when I was testing my code.

Answer (score -2):

According to my investigation, Supertest library is not stable. Majority developers have difficulties to set or retrieve cookies during testing.

You can take a look at this link:
[how to set signed cookies](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/665)